# A couple of resource related questions

Tags: discussion, resources

I've been studying Japanese for a few months following the Genki I textbook combined with the official JLPT N5 book, which I use as a grammar and vocabulary reference. I'm now at a level in which I feel comfortable to work on my reading skills... with Kanji-included sentences. Does anybody know of any resources with sentences that only include JLPT N5 level vocabulary and grammar?

Also, I've found one webpage with a few sentences at that level, but it combines hiragana, romaji and the English translation.  I'm only interested in the hiragana part, for reading purposes.  Does anybody know of a way to remove everything except what is written in hiragana?

Comment: If you're into that, try reading manga for "children" / younger people. They contain furigana above the kanji, so in a pinch you can use those if you can't remember the kanji. I think the kanjis used in those are also generally pretty easy.

Comment: You might also look for "graded readers".